# Old python script not working on mac - needs tkinter

Tags: macos, python

I'm running mojave 10.14.2
I typed this into terminal python -V
and got
Python 2.7.10

I use 3D software called poser, and I had some amazingly useful scripts for this that i bought.  There is one in particular made by D3D (Ralph) who sadly passed away.
The script he made calls for tkinter, but for recent OSs the script fails on my imac pro because there is no tkinter.

If I were to try to load in a more modern version of python eg like 3. something, do you think my scripts that need tkinter possibly work?
Esther (who knows nothing about programming)

Comment: @benwiggy Are you sure about this? I tried on Mojave, executing `import tkinter as tk` results in `ImportError: No module named tkinter`.

Comment: Use a Capital T. Works on Mohave and Mountain Lion.

Comment: @benwiggy Ahh. Python3 isn't that strict :-) Wonder if this is the problem the OP is facing...

Comment: Can you edit the question to add the exact error message you are getting?

Comment: @nohillside - not strictness but a change in the package name to meet standards.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the script calls the system python: `/usr/bin/python`

Make sure that Tkinter is imported as `Tkinter` (with a Capital T). Using all lower case will fail with an error message.

Tkinter is included with the built-in version of python on MacOS, so there must be some other problem on your Mac if Tkinter is not 'there'.

Comment: Although note it is buggy https://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/

Comment: This is the error i get within poser when i try and run the script:-    A Python script was trying to use the Tkinter library.
Tkinter is not compatible with the Mac OS X version of Poser.

If you are a script author, please consider using wxPython instead of Tkinter.

Comment: Even if I knew how to do coding I wouldn't be able to edit the script. I'm not sure it is editable or even if it is legal to decompile someone's script anyway.

Comment: Ah. That puts a different spin on it. There's nothing wrong with the script itself, but Poser is forbidding it from running, for some reason. Are you saying that the same script used to work on the same version of Poser on an earlier MacOS version?

Comment: No I did not use the script in this current version of poser.  But all my tkinter scripts stopped working after an OS upgrade for mac - i forget which one and programmers were told they needed to use wxpython and that tkinter would not work anymore. I have not tried the script since those days until now.

Comment: How did you call the script, then? Python and its libraries have not changed (not even been updated) on MacOS for nearly 10 years! I suspect that you might need to find a poser community to see if anyone there can build a new script with the same functionality.

Comment: I activated the script by locating it from within poser.  But all scripts with tkinter suddenly stopped working at one stage. it was possibly a new version of poser that did it maybe, and not the OS changing, but suddenly all new scripts had to be created with wx python to work to be used in poser mac i was told.  I don't know if anyone else could make a script like that one.  It was very useful

Answer (score 1):

The correct long term solution is to use python 3, however this requires the conversion of python code from version 2 to 3 and this is non trivial.

Another way is to install a version of python 2 that includes Tk. Python can be installed in several ways often by using a package manager like conda, Macports or Homebrew or directly from [python.org](https://www.python.org/downloads/mac-osx/). Normally for python use I would suggest using conda as it manages the installation and use of third party python packages, however in your case as you are just running scripts it might be easier to just use the python.org on.

The latest version for python 2 is 2.7.15 but check that your $PATH has /usr/local/bin before /usr/bin otherwise you will still have the apple python as you have now.